# What is the difference between extends and mixins when using the vue-class-component library?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-class-components

**Heads-up**: We are using Vue 2 and are not planning to switch to the [Composition API](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-introduction.html) (yet). This question is about [vue-class-components](/questions/tagged/vue-class-components).

**Question**: [The documentation of vue-class-components](https://class-component.vuejs.org/guide/extend-and-mixins.html) states that we can use "normal" `extends` to inherit from a single parent component, or to use the `mixins` helper function to inherit multiple mixins.
In my understanding, a parent component is nothing else than a mixin (and vice-versa), thus I would like to know if the following code with a single parent component results in the same child components:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Component from 'vue-class-component'

@Component
export class Parent extends Vue {
  p = 'P'
}

@Component
export class ChildOne extends Parent {
  created () {
    console.log(this.p)
  }
}

@Component
export class ChildTwo extends mixins(Parent) {
  created () {
    console.log(this.p)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case the child components will behave the same way, both will inherit the `p` prop from the Super class.

The main advantage of using `mixins` over `extends` is that you can inherit from multiple classes. Otherwise, if you just need to inherit from one parent class, IMHO then it makes no sense to use mixins

### Example

```
// mixins.js
@Component
export class Rock extends Vue {
  rock = 'rock'
}

@Component
export class Roll extends Vue {
  roll = 'roll'
}
```

```
import { Rock, Roll } from './mixins'

@Component
export class RockAndRoll extends mixins(Rock, Roll) {
  mounted() {
    // now that this is mounted, let's rock and roll
    saySomething()
  }
  
  saySomething() {
    console.log(`let's ${this.rock} and ${this.roll}!`)
  }
}
```